# Azure Function - "Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

when deploying ARM in which: App Service Plan, Storage, Function app with 2 functions are deployed. I have an error while deploying 2 functions:

```
{
"status": "Failed",
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime.",
    "details": [
        {
            "message": "Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime."
        },
        {
            "code": "BadRequest"
        },
        {}
    ]
}
```

I have no idea how more I can debug this and where the error could be.

```
{
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('functionApp'),'/',parameters('project'),'-http-',parameters('environment'))]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('functionApp'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('functionApp'),'/',parameters('project'),'-http-',parameters('environment'))]",
            "scriptFile": "[concat('site/wwwroot/httpTrigger/run.ps1')]",
            "route": "api/{req?}",
            "methods": [
                "GET",
                "POST"
            ],
            "authLevel": "anonymous",
            "direction": "in"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('functionApp'),'/',parameters('project'),'-timerTrigger-',parameters('environment'))]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('functionApp'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('functionApp'),'/',parameters('project'),'-timer-',parameters('environment'))]",
            "scriptFile": "[concat('site/wwwroot/timer/run.ps1')]",
            "timeout": "30",
            "bindings": [
                {
                    "name": "myTimer",
                    "type": "timerTrigger",
                    "direction": "in",
                    "schedule": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Everywhere in the logs there is the same error,

Answer (score -1):

- I have deployed App Service Plan, Storage, Function app with two functions using below arm template.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
        "sites_fn_3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name": {
            "defaultValue": "fn-3sjvfqv5e3qmc",
      "type": "String"
        },
    "serverfarms_FunctionPlan_name": {
            "defaultValue": "FunctionPlan",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "components_AppInsights_name": {
            "defaultValue": "AppInsights",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "vaults_key_3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name": {
            "defaultValue": "key-3sjvfqv5e3qmc",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "storageAccounts_fnstor3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name": {
            "defaultValue": "fnstor3sjvfqv5e3qmc",
      "type": "String"
    }
    },
  "variables": { },
  "resources": [
    {
        "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
      "apiVersion": "2020-02-02",
      "name": "[parameters('components_AppInsights_name')]",
      "location": "westus2",
      "kind": "web",
      "properties": {
            "Application_Type": "web",
        "RetentionInDays": 90,
        "IngestionMode": "ApplicationInsights",
        "publicNetworkAccessForIngestion": "Enabled",
        "publicNetworkAccessForQuery": "Enabled"
      }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
      "apiVersion": "2022-07-01",
      "name": "[parameters('vaults_key_3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name')]",
      "location": "westus2",
      "properties": {
            "sku": {
                "family": "A",
          "name": "Standard"
            },
        "tenantId": "<TenantID>",
        "accessPolicies": [],
        "enabledForDeployment": false,
        "enableSoftDelete": true,
        "vaultUri": "[concat('https://', parameters('vaults_key_3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name'), '.vault.azure.net/')]",
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled"
      }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2022-05-01",
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccounts_fnstor3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name')]",
      "location": "westus2",
      "sku": {
            "name": "Standard_LRS",
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "properties": {
            "minimumTlsVersion": "TLS1_0",
        "allowBlobPublicAccess": true,
        "networkAcls": {
                "bypass": "AzureServices",
          "virtualNetworkRules": [],
          "ipRules": [],
          "defaultAction": "Allow"
        },
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
        "encryption": {
                "services": {
                    "file": {
                        "keyType": "Account",
              "enabled": true
                    },
            "blob": {
                        "keyType": "Account",
              "enabled": true
            }
                },
          "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
        },
        "accessTier": "Hot"
      }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[parameters('serverfarms_FunctionPlan_name')]",
      "location": "West US 2",
      "sku": {
            "name": "Y1",
        "tier": "Dynamic",
        "size": "Y1",
        "family": "Y",
        "capacity": 0
      },
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[parameters('sites_fn_3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name')]",
      "location": "West US 2",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('serverfarms_FunctionPlan_name'))]"
      ],
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "properties": {
            "enabled": true,
        "hostNameSslStates": [
          {
                "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_fn_3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "sslState": "Disabled",
            "hostType": "Standard"
          },
          {
                "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_fn_3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name'), '.scm.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "sslState": "Disabled",
            "hostType": "Repository"
          }
        ],
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('serverfarms_FunctionPlan_name'))]",
        "siteConfig": {
                "numberOfWorkers": 1,
          "acrUseManagedIdentityCreds": false,
          "alwaysOn": false,
          "http20Enabled": false,
          "functionAppScaleLimit": 200,
          "minimumElasticInstanceCount": 0
        }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_fn_3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name'), '/web')]",
      "location": "West US 2",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_fn_3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
            "numberOfWorkers": 1,
        "defaultDocuments": [
          "Default.htm",
          "Default.html",
          "Default.asp",
          "index.htm",
          "index.html",
          "iisstart.htm",
          "default.aspx",
          "index.php"
        ],
        "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
        "virtualApplications": [
          {
                "virtualPath": "/",
            "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
            "preloadEnabled": false
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_fn_3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name'), '/MyHttpTriggeredFunction')]",
      "location": "West US 2",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_fn_3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
            "config": {
                "disabled": false,
          "bindings": [
            {
                    "name": "req",
              "type": "httpTrigger",
              "direction": "in",
              "authLevel": "function",
              "methods": [
                "get"
              ]
            },
            {
                    "name": "$return",
              "type": "http",
              "direction": "out"
            }
          ]
        },
        "language": "CSharp",
        "isDisabled": false
      }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_fn_3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name'), '/Timer-Trigger')]",
      "location": "West US 2",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_fn_3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
            "config": {
                "bindings": [
                  {
                    "name": "myTimer",
              "type": "timerTrigger",
              "direction": "in",
              "schedule": "0 */500* * * *"
                  }
          ]
        },
        "files": null,
        "test_data": "",
        "invoke_url_template": null,
        "language": "CSharp",
        "isDisabled": false
      }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_fn_3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name'), '/', parameters('sites_fn_3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
      "location": "West US 2",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_fn_3sjvfqv5e3qmc_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
            "siteName": "fn-3sjvfqv5e3qmc",
        "hostNameType": "Verified"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- After deploying to azure it will be like below.

[image]

- Click on **Goto resource group** it will Goto **Resource Group** as below.

[image]

- Goto **function app** and navigate to functions you will find as below.

[image]